# How can I utilize the binomial expansion hint for part ii)?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

[image: Question]

I cannot make sense of the expansion hint in ii) and how that could relate to solving this problem, and I would like an explanation of how these 2 hints are useful, preferably further hint before a solution.

(I solved the first part of the question through combinations & permutations and got an answer of 369)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to part (ii) is the same as the answer to "find the coefficient
of $x^6$ in the expansion of
$$(1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+5x^4-6x^5+7x^6-8x^7+9x^8-\cdots)^3$$"
where inside the bracket is the infinite series
$$1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+5x^4-6x^5+7x^6-8x^7+9x^8-\cdots
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(n+1)x^n=\frac1{(1+x)^2}.$$

Comment: I see that you can then do $$(\frac1{(1+x)^2})^3$$ to obtain the final answer, but then how would you compute $$\frac1{(1+x)^6}?$$

Comment: @LHC2012 Binomial theorem?

Comment: It seems I never done binomial theorem with negative powers, so I may have to revise on that. Thank you.